Traefik does not route to my frontend and backend containers correctly
I want to set up traefik to load balance between my containers and while the dashboard on port 8080 works and I can see the correct frontend and backend containers on the routers section, when I try to open "frontend.localhost" or "backend.localhost" it just wouldn't work. Can someone spot the mistake in this easy setup? I dont see any logs in my containers about errors
docker-compose.yml
networks:
  traefiknet: {}

services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v3.1"
    container_name: "traefik"
    command:
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entryPoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--accesslog=true"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
    networks:
      - traefiknet
    
  web:
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod 
    command: gunicorn core.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    env_file:
      - .env.prod
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.web.rule=Host(`web.localhost`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.web.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.services.api-service.loadbalancer.server.port=8000"
    networks:
      - traefiknet

  frontend:
    build: 
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
    depends_on:
      - web
      - traefik
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.rule=Host(`frontend.localhost`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.services.frontend-service.loadbalancer.server.port=3000"
    networks:
      - traefiknet

  whoami:
    image: "traefik/whoami"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`whoami.localhost`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints=web"
    networks:
      - traefiknet

I tried the official documentation/changing some minor syntax stuff too but nothing would work

Please re-read the guidance for the tags you've used.  This is clearly a question about configuring traefik, not about programming, so is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  See Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on? for guidance.

Are you running browser and containers on same host? How do you resolve frontend.localhost? Note that some browsers will automatically resolve any *.localhost to 127.0.0.1.
